# FTP and allowing other users

Tags: php, ftp, chmod

I am trying to allow other people to work on my site with me. There are a couple of files/folders that I do not want them to be able to access / see.

One file is **dbase.php** and the folder is **./crypt/**

How do I go about not even allowing them to see that those files are even there?

One of the guys that I'm trying to allow to work on my site says to use PHP's chmod, I looked it up and it does change the file permissions, but what makes it so that he can't put

```
chmod('dbase.php',0777);
```

in another file like index.php and change the permissions of the database file and then he can see what I have in there. What I'm trying to hide is the password to my database and a few special variables that run my site. Just some things I'm not comfortable letting roam around with people "I don't 100%" know.

Thanks.

Comment: You should have the dbase.php and ./crypt/ in a directory above whatever they have ftp access to.

Comment: Have you considered using a DVCS to develop the site rather than letting other people FTP into it directly and modify files? It's a good idea even completely absent any security considerations.

Comment: What does the User,group and other refer to in permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If the guys you are awaring of should be able to edit and upload PHP code to your site, and your site's PHP code should be able to read the secrets file, the is no solution.

They always can upload the code which reads the secret file and outputs its contents.

Comment: So they could just use file_get_contents(dbase.php); and get whatever they need?